# Using TAB to go to next table row in Excel Online or Google Sheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets

In Excel when you press TAB in the last column in a table it takes you to the first column in the next row.
How to do this in Excel online or Google Sheets?

Pressing tab in Excel online or Sheets always takes you out of the table, is there some solution for this?

Comment: Browser apps need to hijack normal browser key bindings, so I would think that's something that would have to be fixed by the (Excel or Sheets) app itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain similar behaviour if you drag-select an area of cells using the mouse; TAB then moves the active cell through the selected area in the manner described (across the row to the right then next row down beginning on the left).

In addtion, RETURN in this situation moves down columns then across. You can also use SHIFT+TAB or SHIFT+RETURN to move 'backwards' through the selected range. An easy way of highlighting a given range of cells is to define it as a named range, then select it from the Name Box (this selects the whole range).